# Auto scaling of graph-tools output

Tags: python, scaling, graph-tool

I am using graph-tools to produce network graphs automatically from data on a webserver. Some of these graphs have many nodes (10 to 100) and some have 1000's. I would like to produce a consistently sized PNG output, where the nodes are approprimately the same size, between the two graphs. I have a large viewing space available so can generate large pictures if needed.

I have looked at output_size, and was thinking of scaling the pixel tuple accordingly. Has anyone any advice on how best to do this?

[Few nodes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GGr1k.jpg)
[Many nodes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CPNZA.jpg)

Comment: Why can't you set the same vertex size for both the graphs?